# Strange memory loss in embedded java with linux

Tags: java, memory, embedded-linux

I am observing the free memory of my embedded linux (2.6 kernel) system where an "oracle embedded java 1.8 (compact3)" is running. Java is running fine and the memory (RAM) consumption is at a constant level.

I'm monitoring the "free" and "cached" values of the *free* command in a shell.

As shown in the attached image the memory stays at a certain level (blue is the "free" and orange the "cached" value - so the top border line is the total free memory available for linux)

The memory is read every 20s.

Now after about 7:45 hours of operating the java vm there is this strange drop of free memory.

I don't see an increase in the java heap nor any class that is loaded at this time - but the memory of the java process is increased about the amount of dropped memory (~4MB).

The behaviour of the program is normal even after the drop.

Has anyone observed this behaviour too or has an explanation for this?

[Screenshot of free linux memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avrnD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by heap area increase to fulfill some allocation by Java VM (either due to internal needs, or on behalf of program running inside) that could not be fulfilled by previously-mapped heap area. Most in-process memory managers do not return memory back to OS (by unmapping part of heap area) after it is freed by program, instead memory is kept for future use.

Bad signal is if memory consumption constantly increases over time - that may be sign of memory leak.  But just a single increase of process size is usually not something to worry about.